# How to set auth variable in zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, authentication

We are developing a site using ZendFrame work.

We need to set a auth variable(role) to manage user-type.

For that we use a variable `this->view->auth->getIdentity()->role` to manage user-type.

In one chase we are trying to assign the user-type statically.

What is the code to assign the auth variable 'role'.

We tried with `this->view->auth->getIdentity()->role = 'test'`, but it through warning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following should allow you to create a new `Zend_Auth` identity upon successful login :

```
$identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getStorage();
$identity->write($userData);
```

As for the user data, I usually store the database row corresponding to the user with the required fields like Name, surname, email, role, to name a few. If you store a `Zend_Db_TableRow` in the `Zend_Auth` you will be able to access it  like this :

```
Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity()->role;
```

Quick reminder on `Zend_Auth`:

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance(); // get the `Zend_Auth` instance (build on the singleton pattern)

$auth->hasIdentity(); // return true if an indentity exists and false if it doesn't

$auth->getIdentity(); // allow you to get the identity content (array, Zend_Db_TableRow and such)

$auth->write($data): // allow to create a new identity

$auth->clearIdentity(); // destroy any content stored in the identity. Zend_Session::destroy() can also be used since identity is stored in a session variable
```

For more you can read the official documentation : [Zend_Auth](http://framework.zend.com/manual/fr/zend.auth.html)